# Javascript function to compare two thousands separator number not working

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm trying to write a comparator function in javascript which compares two numbers like `'100,000'`, `'200,000'` etc. and returns their difference. I want to use this in the ag-grid's inbuilt custom sorting by '`comparator`' functionality provided here for the Date column: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/

My code is like this:

```
function thousandsComparator(Num1, Num2) {
    var Number1 = thousandsToComparableNumber(Num1);
    var Number2 = thousandsToComparableNumber(Num2);

    if (Number1===null && Number2===null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (Number1===null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (Number2===null) {
        return 1;
    }

    return Number1 - Number2;
}

function thousandsToComparableNumber(num) {
    var total = parseFloat(num.replace(/,/g, ''));
    return total;

}
```

But, it's not working. It's not sorting the column! --> `{headerName: "ORDER Qty", field: "ORDER_QTY", width: 150, comparator: thousandsComparator, unSortIcon: true, cellStyle:{"text-align":"right"}},`

The column data is like this "100,000", "200,000" etc.

Comment: Is this a typo. -> return Number1 - 2Number2;

Comment: not related to the problem, but you should not start your variable name by an uppercase letter.

Comment: could you show us your whole code? perhaps a jsfiddle with it? Thanks

Comment: I've just tried this with version 6.0.4, and it appears to work fine in the sample I wrote. Can you provide a simple plunker that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @SeanLandsman https://ag-grid.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=4214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your plunker you're `dateComparator` which as it stands doesn't take commas into account. You are have `date1, date2)` as arguments to `dateComparator`, but use `date1Number/date2Number` within.

You need to change `dateComparator` to:

```
function dateComparator(date1Number, date2Number) {

    if (date1Number === null && date2Number === null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (date1Number === null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (date2Number === null) {
        return 1;
    }

    return thousandsToComparableNumber(date1Number) - thousandsToComparableNumber(date2Number);
}
```

This will fix your problem, but a better solution would be to leave the data in its raw state and use a cellRenderer to have commas as seperators.

In other words, remove the `dateComparator` altogether, and have the following for your colDef:

```
{
    headerName: "ORDER Qty", 
    field: "ORDER_QTY", 
    width: 150, 
    cellStyle: {
        "text-align": "right"
    },
    cellRenderer: function (params) {
        return Number(params.value).toLocaleString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your cellRendered answer. That's perfect. Is it also possible to add toFixed(2) to this? Maybe like this?? return Number(params.value).toLocaleString().toFixed(2);

Comment: As toLocaleString will return a string, toFixed will fail as this isnt a method on a number,  so if you want it to 2 decimal places, try this: return Number(params.value)..toFixed(2).toLocaleString()

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, and I recommend you to support `nulls` in `thousandsToComparableNumber`

```js
function thousandsComparator(Num1, Num2) {
    var Number1 = thousandsToComparableNumber(Num1);
    var Number2 = thousandsToComparableNumber(Num2);

    if (Number1===null && Number2===null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (Number1===null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (Number2===null) {
        return 1;
    }

    return Number1 - Number2; // there was a typo --> return Number1 - 2Number2;
}

function thousandsToComparableNumber(num) {

    if (num === null){
        return null;
    }

    var total = parseFloat(num.replace(/,/g, ''));
    return total;

}
```

Comment: That was a typo copying pasting here. Not really one in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should try replacing:

return Number1 - 2Number2;

with:

return Number1 - Number2;

Comment: Oh that's a typo copying pasting here. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `null` before you call `thousandsToComparable`, because `null` doesn't have a `.replace()` method, so it gets an error when you try to convert `null`.

```
function thousandsComparator(Num1, Num2) {

    if (Num1===Num2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (Num1===null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (Num2===null) {
        return 1;
    }

    var Number1 = thousandsToComparableNumber(Num1);
    var Number2 = thousandsToComparableNumber(Num2);
    return Number1 - Number2;
}
```